Two straight lines and four times continuously differentiable function intersecting them
This is a question from a previous year exam.
Q. Let $L_1$ denote the line $y = 3x + 2$ and $L_2$ denote the line $y = 4x + 3$. Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a four times continuously differentiable function such that the line $L_1$ intersects the curve $y = f(x)$ at exactly three distinct points and the line $L_2$ intersects the curve $y = f(x)$ at exactly four distinct points. Then, which one of the following is TRUE?
(A) $\frac{df}{dx}$ does not attain the value $3$ on $\mathbb{R}$
(B) $\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}$ vanishes at most once on $\mathbb{R}$
(C) $\frac{d^3 f}{dx^3}$ vanishes at least once on $\mathbb{R}$
(D) $\frac{df}{dx}$ does not attain the value $\frac{7}{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}$
I am quite clueless about the approach to deal with this. Any hints or suggestions will be helpful.

Hint: try the mean value theorem on df/dx

Hint: The requirements on $f$ are quite loose, it can do very much outside of the intersection points with $L_1$ and $L_2$. It should therefore be possible to make counterexamples for the "at most" and "does not" type of statements, by having small wiggles in the function far away from the lines.
